# How to determine which connection string/context from an unknown Entity Framework model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, dbcontext

Pardon my question if this has been asked before but I'm not 100% sure if my google wording is not accurate or if this just isn't a normal thing.

I have a WCF service where I need to pass in any type of Entity Framework model object (unknown by virtue of the fact that I need to treat these objects nearly identically without writing a new interface contract for each model because they all save the same way, for example).

So far, this is great. They're passed in, I seem to be getting the type just fine (I think so far) so I can treat them "generically."

My new conundrum is: How do I get the reference to the database connection string from the entity object?

Is there a way to say something similar to (pardon some of the extreme psuedo here):

```
object DbContext = genericEFObject.databaseEntityConnection; //need help here
typeof(DBContext) db = typeof(DBContext); //possibly help here too
db.Entry(genericEFObject).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
db.SaveChanges();
```

I'd like to avoid passing in the db object to the contract, if possible.

Any awesomeness to be had here?

Comment: Are you using multiple dbcontexts/databases?

Comment: This will eventually be the case as the WCF service will be a universal proxy. We want to make each contract as generic as possible and then write special cases as they are needed.

Comment: Are you looking to be able to do the full CRUD stack, or just creation?

Comment: CRU with support for D. Since we're passing the EF object across the wire, the EF object contains all the data needed to be committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that there's not any remotely easy way to do this. You'll have to write a lot of code and abuse Reflection like it's going out of style. These are your options as far as I can see:

#### Generic method

The DbContext is **not** getting serialized and passed over WCF. So that will leave you with either a POCO Entity object to create, update or delete or a nice long expression tree representing a query. You then have to figure out what DbContext it belongs to, instantiate said DbContext, figure out what DbSet it belongs to, and use it on the DbSet all via reflection.

#### Code generation

You will still need a lot of reflection to pull out all the DbContexts and DbSets but once you have those, generating methods for all of them should be a breeze. You'll have a lot more flexibility as to what conventions you can apply to different operations. The downside is that there will be a lot of code there and it might get a little hard to manage unless you find some way to break it up into different namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on that. I was hoping this was not the case but, alas. I suppose the next best thing is to through the missing parts over the wire to the contract. There are worse ways to have to deal with that, however, so I won't fret. Thank you for taking the time to look into that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the answer is NO - it is not possible to get context instance from an entity object without doing some reflection things. This is generally considered a bad practice to have entities that are aware of the storage they were produced from.

However, because of the way Entity Framework is implemented right now (v6.1.1), technically there is a way to achieve this in a 'hacking manner' when your context configured to create proxies ([ProxyCreationEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.proxycreationenabled(v=vs.113).aspx) = true).

Here's a very bad code that will give you an ObjectContext from an entity object (warning: `do not even consider to use this in production`):

```
var ctx = new MyContext();
ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

dynamic dynamicEntity = ctx.Employees.First();
var entityWrapper = dynamicEntity._entityWrapper;

Type type = entityWrapper.GetType();
var contextProperty = type.GetProperty("Context");
var objectContext = contextProperty.GetValue(entityWrapper) as ObjectContext;
```

Comment: We were looking at some of the things that you mentioned because we saw some interesting promise but stopped when it didn't seem kosher. We knew that doing it this way would involve reflection but to see how hackish it is, I'd bet a monkey and a giraffe that this will go away (and not usable on a production env) and probably isn't as safe as we'd like. Thanks for the answer though.